# AngularJS Authentication issue with query parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To handle authentication, i am using $locationChangeStart.  My code is working fine for the **routeProvider** which does not contains any parameter or query string.  If route provider contains any query parameter,my code is not working fine.

Fo

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html', controller: 'AuthController',auth:false});
    $routeProvider.when('/register', {templateUrl: 'partials/signup.html', controller: 'AuthController',auth:false});
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/:id', controller: 'TestCntrl',auth:false});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});
}]).run(function($rootScope, $route, $location, AutenticationService) {

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(ev, next, current) {

        var nextPath = $location.path();
        var nextRoute = $route.routes[nextPath]

        if(nextRoute.auth && !AutenticationService.isLoggedIn()){
            $location.path("/login");
            // event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

In the above code **nextRoute** checks for the mapping url and fetches property **auth**, which is present in the $routeProvider.But if url contains query parameter nextRoute.auth gives undefined. Because if this authentication is not working.

Any idea, how to handle authentication, if URL contains query string

Answer (score 2):

Just add a check to see if `nextRoute` is not falsy (i.e. undefined). I was running into this when the first route change was triggered. The initial path is usually an empty string, which isn't referenced by any route.

```
if(nextRoute && nextRoute.auth && !AutenticationService.isLoggedIn()){
    $location.path("/login");
}
```

Here is a slightly modified example. You can see the location changing in the console.
http://plnkr.co/edit/oE2Ew8C68t8k8EgKNqtz?p=preview

Another option would be to leverage this project:
https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth

Here is a working demo:
http://angular-client-side-auth.herokuapp.com/login

Comment: i have added this check, but every time login page is displyed

Comment: Sounds good, can come on chat room please. I have to explain few things, so that it will be clear for u

Comment: sure. how do i initiate chat?

Comment: Problem here is, if nextRoute value is undefined, then nextRout.auth will not work. because of this if condition is not executing