# AngularJS - Create a dynamic, generic header

Tags: angularjs

In my AngularJS application, I'm using a router with an ng-view directive.

Besides it I would like to add a generic header (same for all the views). So I did the following:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body ng-app="myApp">
    ...
    <div ng-controller="TopmenuCtrl" class="header">
        <div ng-include="template.url"></div>
        ...
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

The view is dynamic depending on the session token:

```
<!-- views/topmenu.html -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
  <li class="active"><a ng-href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a ng-href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a ng-href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li ng-show="token"><a ng-href="#" ng-click="doLogout()">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

And the topmenu controller with the logout method:

```
// controllers/topmenu.js

$scope.template = {url: 'views/topmenu.html'};

$scope.doLogout = function() {
  localStorageService.clearAll();
  $window.sessionStorage.token = '';
  $location.path('/login');
};
```

The problem is: When I click on "logout" in the app, the topmenu controller is called and destroy the session but the main one from the router is called too and display an error because the session was destroyed!

The only (not satisfactory) solution I found to prevent this is to add this code in each controllers of the app:

```
if ($window.sessionStorage.token = '') {
    return;
}
```

Is there a way to execute the header controller but not the main ng-view controller?

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21699830/resolve-login-in-routeprovider-using-controller/21700696#21700696, and you may get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11672909/900416.

Now my logout link looks like: `<a href ng-click="doLogout()">Logout</a>`.